# Can JavaScript class have an unmount method

Tags: reactjs

I read about the [JavaScript Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) and wonder if like in React there is this `ComponentWillUnmount` and in React functional stateless component there is the React Hook`that can be used to detect unmounting and then run some code before being removed from Doom.

Comment: In React, unmount is called by a caller (which is React renderer). You can have destructor method called unmount or anything else on non-React class but it’s your duty to call it when needed.

Comment: Thanks do you mean I must input some callback into the Javascript Class from a Rect.Comoponent(parent) to be able to get a signal about this?

Comment: The question wasn't clear how React component and JS class are related. It looks like you just ask about a feature that exists in React without using it. In case you use React then yes, you need to call `myClass.destroy()` inside component componentWillUnmount.

Comment: Thanks if the class is inside a React.createContext() I cant see anyone explicitly killing the class then. like so `<FirebaseContext.Provider value={new Firebase()}>
<App />
</FirebaseContext.Provider>` The `Firebase()` above is the JavaScript class pretending to be a Singelton I suppose

Comment: That's correct. A class needs a destructor only if it needs some cleanup